# Making an object active after a few second with coroutine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I'm making a game in which I want the object to start hidden or inactive and after a few seconds appear. I've tried with coroutine but the problem or error is, as I set my object from the start as hidden or inactive, that coroutine needs active objects, so I've tried it from another outside script but still no success. The second script doesn't even start. Does anyone have any suggestions or fixes?

I've tried it from another outside script but still no success. In my added piscture the Num Trigger script just disables the object after collision.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActivationRutine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToActivate;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(StartFunction());
    }

    private IEnumerator StartFunction()
    {
        //Wait for 5 sec.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        //Turn My game object that is set to false(off) to True(on).
        objectToActivate.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The script should run fine as far as `ActivationRutine` component is attached to an **active gameObject** when the scene starts. (obviously, it must not be attached to the `objectToActivate` gameObject)

Comment: Could you share the configuration (perhaps by means of an Inspector screenshot) of the GameObject your script is attached to?

Comment: Ok I will add the screenshot...Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Coroutine at all you could also simply use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) which will still be executed on a disabled object!

You could make it a little component like

```c#
public class DelayedActivation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Automatically activtae the object after delay.\n"
             + "If set to false object has to be activated by another script.\n"
             + "Can still be done delayed using 'ActivateDelayed()'")]
    public bool ActivateOnStart = true;
    public float ActivationDelay = 5.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        if (ActivateOnStart) ActivateDelayed();
    }

    private void AfterDelay()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    /*
     * Activates the object after the configured delay
     */
    public void ActivateDelayed()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(AfterDelay), ActivationDelay);
    }

    /*
     * Activates the object after the passed custom delay
     */
    public void ActivateDelayed(float customDelay)
    {
        Invoke(nameof(AfterDelay), customDelay)
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are objects instead of functions. The are hosted by the gameobject containing the `StartCoroutine()` call. The call itself only adds the coroutine object and schedules it with the unity coroutine scheduler. This means that coroutines are only stopped when the host object is disabled or destroyed, or when the scheduler is told to stop the coroutine through a `StopCoroutine()` call.

You can:

[RECOMMENDED]

A) Host the coroutine at a different object to the ones being inactive/activated. This is best-practice.

---

[NOT RECOMMENDED]

B) Disable components in the object, such as the Renderers, Colliders, and logical scripts disabled, while the object itself remains active. On the activation script, enable the disabled components and scripts.
Snippet:

```
private void Awake() {
    var components = GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>().ToList();
    components.Remove(this);
    foreach (var component in components)
        component.enabled = false;
    StartCoroutine(ActivationCountdown(3f));
}

private void Activate() {
    var components = GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>().ToList();
    components.Remove(this);
    foreach (var component in components)
        component.enabled = true;
    Destroy(this);
}

private IEnumerator ActivationCountdown(float time) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Activate();
}
```

---

The (B) method is NOT recommended because, while the solution is easy in an indiscriminate case where all other components are disabled, it can quickly become a nightmare to work with as soon as you start to need to manage lists of what needs to be activated from start VS activated after a delay. I'd need to setup for each object in editor, or have scripts to manage each case. It become dependency spaghetti.

Hosting the coroutine externally, say, in a singleton, is much easier. You have ONE dependency: Your objects need to call the function on the singleton, referencing themselves as a parameter like I did the variable 'time' in the snippet. Which should be easy to manage, because it's a singleton.